# Freebase Mqlread InvalidURLError: Invalid request URL -- too long -- POST possible?

Tags: freebase

Is it possible to submit a Freebase mqlread request via POST in Python?  I have tried to search for documentation but everything refers to GET.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

You will need issue a `POST` and add a specific header: `X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET` (basically tells the server to emulate a `GET` with the `POST`'s content). Specifically for me I used the `Content-Encoding: application/x-www-form-urlencode`.

Here's the relevant part of my code (coffeescript) if it helps:

```
mqlread = (query, queryEnvelope, cb) ->

    ## build URL
    url = urlparser.format
        protocol: 'https'
        host: 'www.googleapis.com'
        pathname: 'freebase/v1/mqlread'

    ## build POST body
    queryEnvelope ?= {}
    queryEnvelope.key = config.GOOGLE_API_SERVER_KEY
    queryEnvelope.query = JSON.stringify query

    options =
        url: url
        method: 'POST'
        headers:
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET'
            'User-Agent': config.wikipediaScraperUserAgent
        timeout: 3000
        form: queryEnvelope

    ## invoke API
    request options, (err, response, body) ->
        if err then return cb err
        if response.statusCode != 200
            try
                json = JSON.parse(body)
                errmsg = json?.error?.message or "(unknown JSON)"
            catch e
                errmsg = body?[..50]
            return cb "#{response.statusCode} #{errmsg}"
        r = JSON.parse response.body
        decodeStringsInResponse r
        cb null, r
```

Comment: This is correct I believe.
curl https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread -X POST -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override:GET" -d 'query={"id":null,"limit":1}'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think POST is supported for MQLread, but you could use the HTTP Batch facility.

Here's an example in Python:

https://github.com/tfmorris/freebase-python-samples/blob/master/client-library/mqlread-batch.py